# How do I sequentially fill a big range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I want to fill an entire column of Google Sheets with numbers from -4000 to 4000, but I can't find an easy way of doing it.

I'm aware of the auto-fill solution of google sheets that allows you to write two sequential numbers and then select them and use the drag-and-drop approach, but for big numbers, this is not a feasible approach.

Is there a way of automating it using some formula or some built-in option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. input **1** in A1
2. input `=A1 + 1` in A2
3. copy formula from A2
4. press **CMD + Shift + Arrow_down** - this will select entire column except first cell
5. press **CMD + V** to paste formula

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Wanna point out that CMD is the equivalent of CTRL for windows users.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have 8001+ rows and then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(ROW(A1:A4000)*-1); 0; ROW(A1:A4000)})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A8001); {SORT(ROW(A1:A4000)*-1); 0; ROW(A1:A4000)}; ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Please try (in Row1 of a big enough sheet):

```
=ArrayFormula(ROW(A1:A8001)-4001)
```